# In the film "Legend", why is the fairy with a deformed hand with the goblins?

Tags: legend-1985

In the Ridley Scott film, *Legend*, there is a gang of goblins that includes a fairy that has a deformed hand. I've always wondered if he was shunned by his own kind (Gump was a piece of work - maybe he banished him for not being perfect). Was he born with his hand this way? Was he looking for community and therefore tried to join the goblin gang? In a lot of his dialogue he seems to be trying to impress other characters. Like he's really trying hard to fit in and get people to like him.

Answer (score 1):

[It's not entirely explained.](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Blunder)

> Blunder was an elf, brother of Honeythorn Gump's friend Screwball, who for unknown reasons decided to pose as a goblin, masking his identity with a comical, oversized helmet with metal horns. His only stated reason when questioned later was that he'd gone looking for adventure and "found more than I could handle." He joined the company of (real) goblins Blix and Pox and alongside them, served the Lord of Darkness. Sometime while in Darkness' employ, his left hand was transformed into a chicken foot.

From the shooting script:

> GUMP (to Jack): A Buttercup family reunion....!
> I can't believe it.... Last I remember,
> he sold Screwball a jug of dragon's tears
> that turned out to be cow piss!
>
> SCREWBALL: What happened to you?
>
> BLUNDER(flexing his bird claw): It's a long story....
> Let's just say I went look for adventure and
> found more'n I could handle....
> Doesn't matter now anyway... We're all of us
> in the same fix....